# Hadoop C++ WordCount example compiling issues

Tags: c++, hadoop

I am trying to compile the Hadoop wordCout example (`C++`) with the following compile command

```
g++ -o a -L/home/pc/run/hadoop-install/hadoop/lib/native -lhadooppipes -lhadooputils -lpthread -I/home/pc/run/hadoop-install/hadoop/include wordCount.cpp -Wall
```

The Hadoop version is 0.23.5.

The OS is Ubuntu 12.04

However, I get a link error as below:

```
g++ -o a -L/home/pc/run/hadoop-install/hadoop/lib/native -lhadooppipes -lhadooputils -lpthread -I/home/pc/run/hadoop-install/hadoop\
  /include wordCount.cpp -Wall
 6/tmp/cc3Cte9z.o: In function `main':
 7wordCount.cpp:(.text+0x26): undefined reference to `HadoopPipes::runTask(HadoopPipes::Factory const&)'
 8/tmp/cc3Cte9z.o: In function `WordCountMap::map(HadoopPipes::MapContext&)':
 9wordCount.cpp:(.text._ZN12WordCountMap3mapERN11HadoopPipes10MapContextE[WordCountMap::map(HadoopPipes::MapContext&)]+0x2e): undefin\
  ed reference to `HadoopUtils::splitString(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, char const\
  *)'
10/tmp/cc3Cte9z.o: In function `WordCountReduce::reduce(HadoopPipes::ReduceContext&)':
11wordCount.cpp:(.text._ZN15WordCountReduce6reduceERN11HadoopPipes13ReduceContextE[WordCountReduce::reduce(HadoopPipes::ReduceContext\
  &)]+0x26): undefined reference to `HadoopUtils::toInt(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&\
  )'
12wordCount.cpp:(.text._ZN15WordCountReduce6reduceERN11HadoopPipes13ReduceContextE[WordCountReduce::reduce(HadoopPipes::ReduceContext\
  &)]+0x5b): undefined reference to `HadoopUtils::toString(int)'
13collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
14make: *** [a] Error 1
```

Anyone knows where is going wrong?

Comment: Maybe headers are a different version of the .so

Answer (score 0):

Check g++ version in your system, > version 4,  name of source file are put in front of library links. Therefore, in your system the correct order may be:

"g++ wordCount.cpp -o a -L/home/pc/run/hadoop-install/hadoop/lib/native -lhadooppipes -lhadooputils -lpthread -I/home/pc/run/hadoop-install/hadoop/include -Wall"

Hope this helps

/Le Quoc Do